# An extra ' is displayed in the title

Tags: php, title, wp-title

I've found a string that's showing the posts **title - blogname** as title in the browser, but it's adding an extra '

[image: titlebar Firefox]

This is the code I'm using:

```
<title><?php wp_title(‘ | ‘, ‘echo’, ‘right’); ?>  - <?php bloginfo(‘name’); ?></title>
```

I can't see any extra ' so I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those look like smart apostrophes to me. They have a curve on theme. Try:

```
<title><?php wp_title(' | ', 'echo', 'right'); ?> - <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
```

Otherwise post what you have around that php section too.

Comment: thx, who came up with the idea of so many similar characters!